# _tzset and x letter time-zone names

Tags: c, timezone

How can I set, in C, the time zone for Saint Pierre and Miquelon (PMST3PMDT) with this format:

```
set TZ=tzn[+ | –]hh[:mm[:ss] ][dzn]
```

If you look at the documentation of [_tzset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90s5c885%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you can read that:

> tzn
>
> > Three-letter time-zone name, such as PST. You must specify the correct offset from local time to UTC.

What about time zone names of 4 letters (PMDT) or 5 letters (EASST) ?
Here is the list of all the time zone abbreviations: [wikiepedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations)

Here is my simple code in C to test _tzset:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <time.h>
//add _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS in the project properties "preprocessor definitions"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    time_t t;
    struct tm * now;

    _putenv("TZ=PST8PDT"); // for pacific standard time, there is no problem
     _tzset();

    t = time(0);
    now = localtime( & t );
    printf("time: %d:%d \nisdst:%d\n", now->tm_hour, now->tm_min, now->tm_isdst);
    printf("_daylight=%d\n", _daylight);
    printf( "_timezone=%d\n", _timezone);
    printf( "_tzname[0]=%s\n", _tzname[0]);
    printf( "_tzname[1]=%s\n", _tzname[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

*I'm using windows8, visual studio 2012

Comment: Only on Windows do standard functions acquire the `_` prefix.  POSIX says _std and dst
Indicate no less than three, nor more than {TZNAME_MAX}, bytes that are the designation for the standard (std) or the alternative (dst -such as Daylight Savings Time) timezone. Only std is required; if dst is missing, then the alternative time does not apply in this locale._  POSIX also requires `TZNAME_MAX` to be at least 6 (`<limits.h>`).  If Microsoft does not comply with (the current version of) POSIX on this issue, you'll likely have to take the issue up with them -- and the best of British!

Comment: Thanks for your message. I posted the same question on the [Microsoft forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/66c4b173-f7f9-443d-b20a-58a087b8e6af/tzset-and-x-letter-timezone-names?forum=vcgeneral), but I guess I will never have an answer

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the timezone database on Ubuntu:

```
/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab
```

The timezone you want to use is named `America/Miquelon`.

So you would want to do this:

```
setenv("TZ", "America/Miquelon", 1);
tzset();
```

To force the timezone to Saint Pierre & Miquelon.

I do not know whether that would work under MS-Windows though...